# How to use AddDigitalSignatureOriginPart (DocumentFormat.OpenXml library) to secure an Excel file?

Tags: openxml, digital-signature

Need to create a digital signed excel file and then validate the signature when uploaded in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On its own, the `SpreadsheetDocument.AddDigitalSignatureOriginPart()` method does not secure an Excel file. The same is true for the corresponding methods of the `WordprocessingDocument` and `PresentationDocument` classes. Those methods only add an empty `DigitalSignatureOriginPart` that serves as the origin of one or more `XmlSignaturePart` instances, each of which contains a `ds:Signature` element based on the W3C Recommendation [XML Signature Syntax and Processing Version 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) (XMLDSIG).

To secure an Excel file, or any file based on the Open Packaging Conventions (OPC), the most straightforward approach is to use the [PackageDigitalSignatureManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.packagedigitalsignaturemanager?view=netframework-4.8) class, which is contained in the `System.IO.Packaging` namespace as provided by the `WindowsBase.dll` assembly. Thus, if you are targeting the full .NET Framework (e.g., net471), you can use it. However, if you are targeting .Net Core, you need to implement that functionality yourself.

The following code example shows how you can use the `PackageDigitalSignatureManager` class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Linq;

namespace CodeSnippets.Windows.IO.Packaging
{
    public static class DigitalSignatureManager
    {
        public static void Sign(Package package)
        {
            var dsm = new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package)
            {
                CertificateOption = CertificateEmbeddingOption.InSignaturePart
            };

            List<Uri> parts = package.GetParts()
                .Select(part => part.Uri)
                .Concat(new[]
                {
                    // Include the DigitalSignatureOriginPart and corresponding
                    // relationship part, since those will only be added when
                    // signing.
                    dsm.SignatureOrigin,
                    PackUriHelper.GetRelationshipPartUri(dsm.SignatureOrigin)
                })
                .ToList();

            dsm.Sign(parts);
        }

        public static VerifyResult VerifySignature(Package package)
        {
            var dsm = new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package);
            return dsm.VerifySignatures(true);
        }
    }
}
```

In case you need to implement that functionality yourself, it helps to make yourself familiar with a number of sources:

- [The Digital Signing Framework of the Open Packaging Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa905326(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures)
- [System.Security.Cryptography.Xml Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml?view=netframework-4.8)

Based on those sources, I created a partial sample implementation that works with .Net Core. The following snippet shows the `void Sign(OpenXmlPackage, X509Certificate2)` method that takes an `OpenXmlPackage` and an `X509Certificate2` and creates a valid signature:

```cs
        public static void Sign(OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            if (openXmlPackage == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(openXmlPackage));
            if (certificate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(certificate));

            RSA privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
            using SHA256 hashAlgorithm = SHA256.Create();

            // Create KeyInfo.
            var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

            // Create a Signature XmlElement.
            var signedXml = new SignedXml { SigningKey = privateKey, KeyInfo = keyInfo };
            signedXml.Signature.Id = Constants.PackageSignatureId;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = Constants.SignatureMethod;
            signedXml.AddReference(CreatePackageObjectReference());
            signedXml.AddObject(CreatePackageObject(openXmlPackage.Package, hashAlgorithm));
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement signature = signedXml.GetXml();

            // Get or create the DigitalSignatureOriginPart.
            DigitalSignatureOriginPart dsOriginPart =
                openXmlPackage.GetPartsOfType<DigitalSignatureOriginPart>().FirstOrDefault() ??
                openXmlPackage.AddNewPart<DigitalSignatureOriginPart>();

            var xmlSignaturePart = dsOriginPart.AddNewPart<XmlSignaturePart>();

            // Write the Signature XmlElement to the XmlSignaturePart.
            using Stream stream = xmlSignaturePart.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            using XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
            signature.WriteTo(writer);
        }
```

The full source code of the above `void Sign(OpenXmlPackage, X509Certificate2)` method can be found in my [CodeSnippets](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets) GitHub repository. Look for the [DigitalSignatureManager](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets/blob/master/CodeSnippets/IO/Packaging/DigitalSignatureManager.cs) class in the CodeSnippets project.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I did look into those code snippets and found a DS variable which is never declared. Couldn't figure out what it was.

Comment: @SonMauri, are you talking about the [DS](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets/blob/master/CodeSnippets/IO/Packaging/DS.cs) class? It sits in the same folder as the DigitalSignatureManager class.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out you can simply click on the variable and it shows where it's declared. After I included those classes the code signed an Excel document but sadly, the signature appears to be invalid. I had to change the return type to OpenXmlPackage and return the input document (var name openXmlPackage). On the callers end I took that output and wrote it to a file with a different name... but invalid signature.

Comment: It does not work